# What's a good book (or other resource) to learn Imitation Learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I must learn and apply imitation learning on a robot for my thesis. I'm looking for decent sources of information on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a great book, it's just what I was looking for. In case someone finds it useful:

[*An Algorithmic Perspective on Imitation Learning: T. Osa, J. Pajarinen, G. Neumann, J. A. Bagnell, P. Abbel, & J Peters.*](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1811/1811.06711.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Imitation Learning is a new emerging field in Machine Learning. I would suggest to read a google scholarly articles.

Here are some resources to get started:

1) https://sites.google.com/view/icml2018-imitation-learning/ (To get basic understanding)

2) https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3054912

3) http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4545-imitation-learning-by-coaching

4) http://proceedings.mlr.press/v48/ho16.pdf

Comment: I'd suggest adding a small summary of each link explaining what's in them and the title of the article. Links are prone to disappear so it's useful to know what you are looking for in case the link goes away.

Comment: @Bhanu Sreekar Reddy: Wow, thank you!